# Terribly degraded performance with other join conditions in $lookup (using pipeline)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

So during some code review I decided to improve existing query performance by improving one aggregation that was like this:

```js
    .aggregate([
        //difference starts here
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "sessions",
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "_client",
                "as": "sessions"
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$sessions"
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "sessions.deleted_at": null
            }
        },
        //difference ends here
        {
            $project: {
                name: client_name_concater,
                email: '$email',
                phone: '$phone',
                address: addressConcater,
                updated_at: '$updated_at',
            }
        }
    ]);
```

to this:

```js
    .aggregate([
    //difference starts here
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'sessions',
            let: {
                id: "$_id"
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and:
                                [
                                    {
                                        $eq: ["$_client", "$$id"]
                                    }, {
                                    $eq: ["$deleted_at", null]
                                },
                                ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: 'sessions'
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "sessions": {$ne: []}
        }
    },
    //difference ends here
        {
            $project: {
                name: client_name_concater,
                email: '$email',
                phone: '$phone',
                address: addressConcater,
                updated_at: '$updated_at',
            }
        }
    ]);
```

I thought that the second option should be better, since we have one less stage, but the difference in performance is massive in the opposite way, the first query runs on average ~40ms, the other one ranges between 3.5 - 5 seconds, 100 times more. The other collection (sessions) has around 120 documents, while this one about 152, but still, even if it was acceptable due to data size, why the difference between these two, isn't it basically the same thing, we are just adding the join condition in the pipeline with the other main condition of the join. Am I missing something?

Some functions or variables included there are mostly static or concatenation that shouldn't affect the $lookup part.

Thanks

EDIT:

Added query plans, for version 1:

```js
{
        "stages": [
            {
                "$cursor": {
                    "query": {
                        "$and": [
                            {
                                "deleted_at": null
                            },
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    "fields": {
                        "email": 1,
                        "phone": 1,
                        "updated_at": 1,
                        "_id": 1
                    },
                    "queryPlanner": {
                        "plannerVersion": 1,
                        "namespace": "test.clients",
                        "indexFilterSet": false,
                        "parsedQuery": {
                            "deleted_at": {
                                "$eq": null
                            }
                        },
                        "winningPlan": {
                            "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                            "filter": {
                                "deleted_at": {
                                    "$eq": null
                                }
                            },
                            "direction": "forward"
                        },
                        "rejectedPlans": []
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "sessions",
                    "as": "sessions",
                    "localField": "_id",
                    "foreignField": "_client",
                    "unwinding": {
                        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": false
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "_id": true,
                    "email": "$email",
                    "phone": "$phone",
                    "updated_at": "$updated_at"
                }
            }
        ],
        "ok": 1
    }
```

For version 2:

```js
{
        "stages": [
            {
                "$cursor": {
                    "query": {
                        "deleted_at": null
                    },
                    "fields": {
                        "email": 1,
                        "phone": 1,
                        "sessions": 1,
                        "updated_at": 1,
                        "_id": 1
                    },
                    "queryPlanner": {
                        "plannerVersion": 1,
                        "namespace": "test.clients",
                        "indexFilterSet": false,
                        "parsedQuery": {
                            "deleted_at": {
                                "$eq": null
                            }
                        },
                        "winningPlan": {
                            "stage": "COLLSCAN",
                            "filter": {
                                "deleted_at": {
                                    "$eq": null
                                }
                            },
                            "direction": "forward"
                        },
                        "rejectedPlans": []
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "sessions",
                    "as": "sessions",
                    "let": {
                        "id": "$_id"
                    },
                    "pipeline": [
                        {
                            "$match": {
                                "$expr": {
                                    "$and": [
                                        {
                                            "$eq": [
                                                "$_client",
                                                "$$id"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "$eq": [
                                                "$deleted_at",
                                                null
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "$match": {
                    "sessions": {
                        "$not": {
                            "$eq": []
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "_id": true,
                    "email": "$email",
                    "phone": "$phone",
                    "updated_at": "$updated_at"
                }
            }
        ],
        "ok": 1
    }
```

One thing of note, the joined sessions collection has certain properties with very big data (some imported data), so I am thinking that in some way it may be affecting the query size due to this data? But why the difference between the two $lookup versions though.

Comment: What are the query plans for each of the versions?

Comment: @Oleg Thanks, added them in the post. Also removed the concatenation functions, limit, offset, and such to make the output of the explain shorter. One thing though, after removing the limit, the pipeline version jumped to over 10 seconds, what the hell.

Comment: @Ncifra, I'm curious, what's your MongoDB version?

Comment: @TheeSritabtim 4.0.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version adds an aggregation pipeline execution *for each document in the joined collection*.

[The documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) says:

> Specifies the pipeline to run on the joined collection. The pipeline determines the resulting documents from the joined collection. To return all documents, specify an empty pipeline [].

The pipeline is executed for each document in the collection, not for each matched document.

Depending on how large the collection is (both # of documents and document size) this could come out to a decent amount of time.

> after removing the limit, the pipeline version jumped to over 10 seconds

Makes sense - all of the additional documents due to the removal of limit also must have the aggregation pipeline executed for them.

It is possible that per-document execution of aggregation pipeline isn't as optimized as it could be. For example, if the pipeline is set up and torn down for each document, there could easily be more overhead in *that* than in the $match conditions.

> Is there any case when using one or the other?

Executing an aggregation pipeline per joined document provides additional flexibility. If you need this flexibility, it may make sense to execute the pipeline, though performance needs to be considered regardless. If you don't, it is sensible to use a more performant approach.

Comment: So it's sort of no_documents_coll1*no_documents_coll2 in terms of how many documents are scanned?

I don't understand though, is this something wrong on MongoDB's end, or wrong usage on my side, since for me this is sort of "following the usage documentation". It seems like the pipeline inside lookup is syntactic sugar for something that is not very visible when using it.

Comment: Seems there already is something about this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-41171

Comment: What does "pipeline inside lookup is syntactic sugar" mean? You are asking the database to perform additional work. You can reason that the result of that work is equivalent to a result of another operation, or (oversimplifying) not performing the work at all. But you still asked the database to perform the work, and if it's implemented in a straightforward manner it will be performing that work even if the work doesn't affect the outcome in this particular case.

Comment: I meant that even though it "seems" like you are doing less operations, since you are within one stage of the main aggregation pipeline (no $unwind and such, extra stages), you are doing extra work, that's why I said the syntactic sugar part, which makes it seem like you are doing something that is not quite what really happens, like the await/async that makes it seem like you are doing synchronous actions, even though you are still in asynchronous.

Comment: Not to lose the main purpose of the question though: Is there any case when using one or the other? Considering also the JIRA issue, I am assuming that the second version is degraded so for now there's no reason why move to it even though there is some less code.

Comment: I suspect that, since the second version is a more flexible approach, it offers a more dynamic matching condition which will be harder to optimise, so it will generally do a full collection scan. The first version has a condition that can be statically analysed and optimised using index.

Comment: What I was thinking in regards to this is if indexing the "deleted_at" property will make a difference, but seeing the very noticeable difference currently I don't think it will be a solution, it may improve performance, but still it's a not optimized operation. I've worked previously with not indexed fields, but the difference is noticeable with big data sets, and still not this much.