# how to reduce unnecessary unwind stages from aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, optimization, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Like if i'm applying many lookup stages in aggregation pipeline and each lookup is followed by an unwind(just to covert into object) first question does it affect query performance? and if yes how to do that in optimised manner

Note: all lookup's will return only one object

For Ex:

```
xyz.aggregate([
{ $lookup:{ ----}} //first lookup
{$unwind :{----}} //first unwind
{ $lookup:{ ----}} //second lookup
{$unwind :{----}} //second unwind
{ $lookup:{ ----}} //third lookup
{$unwind :{----}} //third unwind
{ $lookup:{ ----}} //fourth lookup
{$unwind :{----}} //fourth unwind
])
```

Comment: since there are so many `lookup` stages, I would recommend you to replace them all with just one but `advanced` lookup that has pipeline option.

Comment: Is each lookup returning a single document?

Comment: yes they all are returning single document as i'm using it as a alternate to populate

Comment: @Lahori i'm not quite clear with your suggestion can you share some links of documentation or example

Comment: @harshitkohli official docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup
example docs: http://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-36-lookup-expr.html

Comment: @Lahori I don't think you can always replace multiple `$lookup`s and `$unwind`s with an advanced `$lookup`. I think those multiple $lookups in the question are from different collections. Advanced `$lookup` could also be slower than a classic `$lookup` as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61614202

Comment: @TheeSritabtim You can still you use advanced lookup even if they are from different collections since I have done that myself i.e. 5 different collections. As far as performance is concerned, there must be some bug or some other issue on mongo side.

Comment: just a thought if we add new single project stage replacing all unwind in which we can simply project element at 0 index(first element) is that worth trying?

Comment: @Lahori nice to know that's possible, thanks.

Comment: @harshitkohli thats absolutely possible & I believe in your case this is the best solution but don't forget to use $arrayElemAt to avoid array as a result of $project.

Comment: @Lahori yes i did the same it worked for me. just curious to know how to apply advanced lookup on multiple collection in single stage? if you could provide some example that would be really helpful!

Comment: Be sure to measure performance with the advanced $lookup with pipeline, from my experience it's usually slower than the usual $lookup. This might be due to an issue from mongodb as @Lahori mentioned, but it's still affecting performance nevertheless

Comment: ya sure @TheeSritabtim i'm just asking it for learning purpose.i'm not implementing it in production as things are working quite good with my approach

Comment: If the lookups ever return more than 1 document, unwinding them all will result in duplicating all of the others.  So if  each of the 4 lookups returned 2 documents, there would be 16 documents in the output.  Using $addFields with $arrayElemAt would allow you to grab just the first document without that risk.

Comment: @Joe yes you're right but in my case i'm just using it to populate reference key so this case will never occur! thanks man i'll edit the question so that everyone could understand  the use case

Answer (score 1):

In reference to comments, here is advanced `$lookup`:

```
$lookup: {
        from: 'accounts',
        let: { "localAccountField": "$account" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $eq: ["$_id", "$$localAccountField"]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              user: 1
            }
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'users',
              let: { 'localUserField': "$user" },
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $match: {
                    $expr: {
                      $eq: ["$_id", "$$localUserField"]
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  $project: {
                    _id: 1,
                    username: "$uid",
                    phone:"$phoneNumber",
                    email: "$email.add",
                    name: {
                      $concat: [
                        "$profile.name.first",
                        ' ',
                        "$profile.name.last"
                      ]
                    },
                  }
                }
              ],
              as: "users"
            }
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'documents',
              let: { 'localDocumentField': "$user" },
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $match: {
                    $expr: {
                      $eq: ["$user", "$$localDocumentField"]
                    },
                    status:"verified",
                    "properties.expirydate": { $exists: true, $ne: "" },
                    name: "idcard"
                  }
                },
                {
                  $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    cnic: "$properties.number"
                  }
                }
              ],
              as: "documents"
            }
          }
        ],
        as: 'account'
      }
```