# MongoDB sorting data fails

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

im trying to sort around 40k objects in mongo, what i have is two collections, one of comics and other of characters, characters have a field inside with an array of comic ids where they appear. What i want is a pipeline for the aggregation framework that retrieves the comic with the strongest characters (sum of the strength of each character). I am capable of getting the list of comics with the sum of the strength of each character, however when i try to sort it, the database keeps waiting and everything ends up in a timeout. What am i doing wrong?

Characters model:

```
{
  _id: number,
  name: string,
  info: {
    alignment: string // can be "good" or "bad"
  }
  stats: {
    strength: number
  },
  comics: [] //array of numbers referencing the id of the comic
}
```

Comics model:

```
{
  _id: number,
  name: string
}
```

And here my query:

```
db.comics.aggregation(
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'characters',
                    let: {
                        comic_id: '$_id',
                    },
                    as: 'total_comic_str',
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $and: [
                                        {$in: ['$$comic_id', '$comics']}, // the character is from this comic
                                        {$eq: ['$info.alignment', 'good']} // the character is a hero
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $group: {  // group by comic id and accumulate strength of each hero
                                _id: '$$comic_id',
                                str: {
                                    $sum: '$stats.strength'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: {
                    path: '$total_comic_str',
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    'total_comic_str.str': -1
                }
            },
            {
                $limit: 1
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a cursor timeout.
When you have a query cursor (like what returns by `find()`) you can set [noCursorTimeout()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.noCursorTimeout/#cursor.noCursorTimeout) (which is generally not a good practice) to prevent the issue.
But when using an aggregation, the Cursor type is different so there is no `noCursorTimeout`.

As a solution, you can use the [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) pipeline to store aggregation result into a temporary collection, then working with the generated collection as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

`$lookup` with pipeline has [shown to have performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61614202) for large collections

So I would suggest using just the `$lookup` without pipeline. This will work for your particular dataset that have relatively large `characters` collection and presumably smaller `comics` arrays

First, it's better to index what you are going to use in `$lookup`, so you should add an index for the field `comics` for this to have a meaningful improvement.

Since the characters will a subdocument array, We are going to use [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) instead of `$group` to calculate total strength

Your aggregation pipeline should look like this

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "characters",
      localField: "_id", // lookup with _id only we will filter out alignment later
      foreignField: "comics",
      as: "characters"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: true,
      total_strength: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$characters",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $add: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: [ "$$this.info.alignment", "good"] }, // calculating only "good" character here
                  "$$this.stats.strength",
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    $sort: { total_strength: -1 }
  }, 
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
]
```